# Calling A Java Library From Pentaho Kettle

Tags: java, class, package, pentaho, kettle

I have developed a java class exported into a .jar library that will be called by a Pentaho Kettle 'modified java script'. The .jar is compiled in Eclipse with JDC Compliance level 1.7.

When I try to use this class inside a 'modified java script', I get the error: ReferenceError: “xeroCallPackage” is not defined. I have tried lots of things without much luck so far.

My file xeroCallPackage.jar is in the path with the other *.jar files in Pentaho (..\data-integration\lib)

For info:

The stripped down (for simplicity) java library code is here:

```
package xeroCallPackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

public class xeroURLCall {

    public String getResponse(String CONSUMER_KEY, String CONSUMER_PRIVATE_KEY, String URL) throws IOException, OAuthException, URISyntaxException { 

        // stripped out code here
        return response.readBodyAsString();
    }

}
```

The stripped down Pentaho 'modified java script' is here:

```
var CONSUMER_KEY = "ffffff";
var CONSUMER_PRIVATE_KEY = "aaaaa";
var URL = "https://gggggggg.rrrrr.wwww";

var ResponseAsString;

ResponseAsString = new     xeroCallPackage.xeroURLCall.getResponse(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_PRIVATE_KEY,URL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either have to have `org` as top-most package or prefix the fully qualified name of your class with `Packages`.

So in your case the fully qualified name of your class that can be used for calling from Spoon will be `Packages.xeroCallPackage.xeroURLCall`

Apart from that the supplied JavaScript code won't work (but maybe that's just because of the stripped down code). You'd have to create a `xeroURLCall` object first and then call the `getResponse` method on that object:

```
var call = new Packages.xeroCallPackage.xeroURLCall(...);
var responseAsString = call.getResponse(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_PRIVATE_KEY,URL);
```